# TinyMCE stripping javascript from link on visual tab

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, tinymce

TinyMCE is removing the javascript from the following link when I use the `Visual` tab.

```
<a href="/home/" onclick="trackOutboundLink('/home/', 'Home Page', 'link 1'); return false;">Home</a>
```

The `onclick="trackOutboundLink('/home/', 'Home Page', 'link 1'); return false;"` code disappears when I go to the `Visual` tab of TinyMCE. I'm using TinyMCE in the context of Wordpress.

Is possible to use the visual tab of the TinyMCE editor without erasing my javascript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE editor strips out elements that are not specified as valid.  These [valid elements are specified during setup of the editor](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements).

I am not familiar with WordPress, but it sounds like you need to [install this WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-tinymce-configuration/) to allow advanced configuration of the TinyMCE editor.  This would allow you to specify `onlick` as a valid attribute for the `a` tag.

Also, take a look at this [article I found on wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/extended_valid_elements-adjusted-to-allow-a-href-onclick-attribute).  This person seemed to be having a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to install the advanced tinyMCE configuration plugin and add my own customization. `extended_valid_elements : a[accesskey|charset|class|contenteditable|contextmenu|coords|dir|download|draggable|dropzone|hidden|href|hreflang|id|lang|media|name|rel|rev|shape|spellcheck|style|tabindex|target|title|translate|type|onclick|onfocus|onblur]`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had the wrong editor plugin installed.

I had installed Advanced Editor Tools (previously TinyMCE Advanced) and Advanced TinyMCE Configuration. These are the correct ones.

I also had the Classic Editor plugin installed and this caused the extended_valid_elements settings to be ignored. No doubt any other third-party editor plugin will cause the same problem.

As soon as I deactivated Classic Editor, it worked! :)